# Camunda Modeler: Access constant column's value in output column in Camunda Modeler UI

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, camunda-plugin

I am new in Camunda and I am learning.
I want to add a constant column either in the input or output section in Camunda Modeler. and I want to access this constant for some calculations and send the output.

In the below Camunda modeler, I have a column **num** (Expression: `payload.num`) and a constant column **constant** (Expression: `constant`). I want to send the output by the formula `constant*payload.num`.

[image]

**And here is my curl:**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/engine/default/decision-definition/key/const_id/evaluate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "variables": {
        "payload": {
            "value": {
                 "num":1
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

**and I am getting this error:**
**In Postman:**

```
{
    "type": "RestException",
    "message": "Cannot evaluate decision const_id:9:6522be72-1cdd-11ee-adea-00ff092b2785: Exception while evaluating decision with key 'null'",
    "code": 0
}
```

[image]

I want to output something like (**without passing constant as input**):

```
[
    {
        "output": {
            "value": 5,
        }
    }
]
```

**Error in Camunda Modeler CMD:**

```
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.dmn.feel.impl.FeelException: FEEL/SCALA-01008 Error while evaluating expression: failed to evaluate expression 'constant': no variable found for name 'constant'
```

[image]

Please help me where I am doing wrong, or How can I access constant column value either from Input or from one output's column to another output's column?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**I explored and got the solution (workaround) to achieve this.**

We can create the decision table like this:

[image]

In that decision table, we have two column names (expression - `payload.num`) as input and Constant (Expression - `constant`) as output.

The output will be input in one of the expression table (can call a decision table, but it will return an expression.)

Now, we need to create a decision table but in this, we will return an expression.
the expression would be:

```
{
"result":constant*payload.num
}
```

[image]

**This is how we can call API in Postman and get the results:**

[image]